# Matplotlib error in axis drawing

Tags: matplotlib, flask

I'm using `Flask` to generate graphs on a certain endpoint and send them to the browser. I update the data that I am graphing, but nothing else. I call the `/graph` endpoint once every 2 seconds, but the plot changes dramatically in that time. Examples are below:

[image]

[image]
[image]

This is the code that I am using:

```
@app.route('/graph')
def graph_ep():
    fig = plt.figure()

    # Matplotlib setup
    style.use('fivethirtyeight')  # Make the graphs look better

    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(x, y, marker='o', label="Heart Data")
    ax1.plot(x, LRL_data, marker='o', label="Lower Rate Limit")
    ax1.plot(x, URL_data, marker='o', label="Upper Rate Limit")
    ax1.set(xlabel="Time",
        ylabel="Beats per Minute",
        title="Moving Average of Heart Rate")

    ax1.legend(loc="upper center")

    ax1.grid(True)

    # Change y axis
    ax1.set_ylim(0,2.5)
    x1, x2, y1, y2 = plt.axis()
    plt.axis((x1,x2,0.0, 2.5))
    y_axis = [float(i)/10.0 for i in range(0,25,2)]
    plt.yticks(y_axis)

    time_string = str(int(time.time()))
    file_name = 'static/graphs/real/graph' + time_string + '.png'

    plt.savefig(file_name)

    return '<img src="' + file_name + '">'
```

How can I keep all the features of the graph (axes, axis labels, grid, etc) the same as the first image while only updating the data?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the data in the array `y` was inconsistent. I had strings and floats in it at the same time, which was confusing `matplotlib`. For example, `[0.0, 0.1, '0.2', '0.3', '0.4']`. Once I converted the strings to floats, the issue was mostly resolved. However, the axis labels are still hidden.